# How to generate a symmetric key using sjcl

Tags: javascript, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, sjcl

Is it possible to generate symmetric keys using sjcl? I want to return the symmetric key rather than just calling the `sjcl.encrypt()` function.
Please provide a code example if possible.

Comment: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/wiki/Symmetric-Crypto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it is done.
`const key = sjcl.random.randomWords(8)(for a 256-bit key)`
I got the answer from Nil Kenneweg, on a different forum.